# How set stretch factor for chart in Pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Now the application displays two graphs with the same height:

[image]

CODE:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Draw_interface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        global time_update

        super(Draw_interface, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('charts.ui', self)

        # Add two charts
        self.my_draw = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.p1 = self.my_draw.addPlot(row=0, col=0, stretch=3)
        self.p2 = self.my_draw.addPlot(row=1, col=0, stretch=1)

        # Set widget for chart
        my_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        my_layout.addWidget(self.my_draw)
        self.frame_for_charts.setLayout(my_layout)

        # Draw charts
        y = [2.2, 3.0, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.2, 5.5, 6.6]
        y2 = [2.3, 3.3, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.1, 2.8, 4.4]
        curve1 = self.p1.plot(y)
        curve2 = self.p2.plot(y2)

        self.show()

my_app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
my_main_window = Draw_interface()
sys.exit(my_app.exec_())
```

`stretch=3` and `stratch=1` - do not lead to the desired effect.

**How to set the stretch factor** correctly so that the upper graph is 75% of the height, the lower graph is 25% of the height?
And it was like this:

[image]

Maybe:

```
self.my_draw.itemAt(0, 0).setGeometry(x1,y1,x2,y2)
self.my_draw.itemAt(0, 0).updateGeometry()
```

But this is clearly not the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter like "stretch" or "stratch" for `addPlot` method.

If you want to use `GraphicsLayoutWidget`, you can add empty labels to take up spaces of the next column to serve as a reference of the grid.(kind of hacky...)

Or you can put 2 plotwidget inside `QVBoxLayout` and use "stretch" parameter in `addWidgets` method.

The result using `QVBoxLayout` is more accurate.

`GraphicsLayoutWidget` solution.
[image]

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Draw_interface(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Draw_interface, self).__init__()
  
        # Add two charts
        self.my_draw = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.p1 = self.my_draw.addPlot(row=0, col=0, rowspan = 3)
        self.p2 = self.my_draw.addPlot(row=3, col=0)

        # Add label with no text to take up spaces of the next column 
        self.p3 = self.my_draw.addLabel(text='',row=0, col=1)
        self.p4 = self.my_draw.addLabel(text='',row=1, col=1)
        self.p5 = self.my_draw.addLabel(text='',row=2, col=1)
        self.p6 = self.my_draw.addLabel(text='',row=3, col=1)
        
        # Draw charts
        y = [2.2, 3.0, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.2, 5.5, 6.6]
        y2 = [2.3, 3.3, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.1, 2.8, 4.4]
        self.p1.plot(y)
        self.p2.plot(y2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.my_draw)
        
    
def main():
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    main = Draw_interface()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`QVBoxLayout` solution.
[image]

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Draw_interface(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Draw_interface, self).__init__()
  
        # Add two charts
        p1 = pg.PlotWidget(name = "Plot1")
        p2 = pg.PlotWidget(name = "Plot2")
        
        # Draw charts
        y = [2.2, 3.0, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.2, 5.5, 6.6]
        y2 = [2.3, 3.3, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.1, 2.8, 4.4]
        p1.plot(y)
        p2.plot(y2)

        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(p1, stretch=3)
        l.addWidget(p2, stretch=1)

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: black; }")
    
def main():
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    main = Draw_interface()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Also see answer here: [Unequal sizes for subplots in pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299869/unequal-sizes-for-subplots-in-pyqtgraph)

Not sure if this is meant to be part of pyqtgraph's public API, but I was able to get row stretching of items in a `pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget` with the following:

The following result gave plot0 to be twice as large as plot1.

```py
graphics_layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
plot0 = graphics_layout.addPlot(row=0, col=0)
plot1 = graphics_layout.addPlot(row=1, col=0)
graphics_layout.ci.layout.setRowStretchFactor(0, 2) # row 0, stretch factor 2
graphics_layout.ci.layout.setRowStretchFactor(1, 1) # row 1, stretch factor 1
```